# Is that possible to send a file to a zebra printer to print it by a web application on a phone using just WI-FI?

Tags: web-applications, wifi, zebra-printers, smartphone

I'll have a web application that is mostly going to be used on phones (iOS or Android) and I want to deal with files on this application and send them to a Zebra Printer that only has wi-fi connection. Both phone and the printer will be at the same wlan. Does anybody know about this? Do I need a desktop? What can I do?

I've been looking for answers but since I have never worked with printers before it is hard to know if there is a simple solution for this. The zebra printers don't have bluebooth, only wi-fi.